# Questions in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I have two question which I couldn't solve:

1. Let $G$ be a group of size $40$.

a. Show the $5$-Sylow subgroup in $G$ is Normal - this part was easy, I just showed that $n5=1$ and then $P5$ is normal.

b. Show that there are $H_1< H_2 < H_3$ in $G$ with $|H_1|=5,|H_2|=10,|H_3|=20$.
I tried to solve b but without a success, What I thought is that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_8$ (Chinese remainder theorem) and then i tried to find a subgroup of size $10$ in it, and to show that $P5$ is in there,but things went wrong.

The second question is:

2. Let $A,B,C$ be finitely generated abelian groups. Assume that $A\times B$ isomorphic to $A\times C$. Prove: $B\times C$.

I tried to use the theorem which says that every finitely generated abelian group isomorphic to Z^nX{primaric groups}. but still didn't know how to continue with that.

I would like to get help in questions 1b and 2, thanks.

Comment: $G$ need not be abelian, so you need to be more careful in 1b. Hint: You have a normal subgroup of order $5$, so you can use the correspondence theorem on the quotient.

Answer (score 0):

For 1b) Let $H_1$ be the 5-Sylow subgroup. Since $H_1$ is normal in $G$, consider $G'= G/H_1$. This is a group of order 8, and so has subgroups of orders 2 and 4. Now use the correspondence theorem to get subgroups in $G$ of the required sizes.

For 2) It suffices to assume that $A=\mathbb{Z}$ or $A = \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$. For the former, you could tensor by $\mathbb{Q}$ and compare dimension of the resultant $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. For the latter, you could just compare the invariant factors on either side. Does that not work?